# extended PCA (tangled matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given an $m$ by $n$ matrix $A$ and the constant $r$, the principal component analysis allows us to find matrices $W$ and $H$ so that the $WH$ gives a lower rank approximation of $A$. In other words,

$A_{m\times n} \cong W_{m\times r}H_{r\times n}$

where $W$ is an $m$ by $r$ matrix and $H$ is an $r$ by $n$ matrix such that $|A-WH|^2$ is minimized. ($r$ is smaller than $m$ and $n$)

Now we have a different but related problem, which I was wondering if it can be solved in similar way. Instead of one matrix A, we are given two matrices $A_{m\times n}$ and $B_{m\times p}$ and the constants $r$ and $\lambda$. We want to find three matrices $W_{m\times r}$,$H_{r\times n}$ and $G_{r\times p}$ such that

$A \cong WH$

$B \cong WG$

The objective function that we want to minimize is:

$C = |A-WH|^2+ \lambda .  |B-WG|^2$

How can we find the optimal $W$,$H$ and $G$ matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess a simple solution would be as follows:

Form the matrix D by merging A and B,

$D_{n\times(m+p)}=[A|\sqrt{\lambda} B]$

then solve the PCA for D.

$D\cong WK$

Then the solution to the original problem is:

$W=W$,

$[H|\sqrt{\lambda} G]=K$

In fact similar approach would be applicable to other matrix factorization methods such as NMF and its variants.